# How to turn on LED with PMOD on FPGA

Tags: led, fpga

I have a 12 pin PMOD interface on my Nandland Goboard FPGA and I would like to turn on an external LED with it.

I can do it on my using pins 5 and 6 which are [GND and VCC](http://digilentinc.com/Pmods/Digilent-Pmod_%20Interface_Specification.pdf) but I can't figure out how to turn it on using one of the pins controlled by the FPGA. Do I hook the LED to ground and one of the output pins set to logic 1?

Or is it supposed to be output pin logic 1 and VCC? Or some combination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you can control each PMOD signal independently, I would build this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1yO8S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This will allow you to power the LED with about 15 mA; my understanding is the max output from the PMOD signals are 8 mA. When the PMOD GPIO is 1, the LED is on, and off otherwise.